# Redirect all active users to specific page without they send any request

Tags: php, laravel

If you are using two steps authentication on facebook and tried to login, facebook will ask you for a code from you phone.
At the same time before you receive the code, if you are logged in another device you will see a message asking you if you was trying to login

If you press "yes it was me" facebook redirect you from "enter code" page to your account immediately without doing any thing

Now i want to make something similar in laravel

I want if admin pressed "redirect all user to .... Page" button
Server redirect all users **immediately** to this page

Comment: For Facebook's specific implementation, they are probably polling on the login form for a specific server response. For you, you'd have to poll on every page, I guess. You can poll through AJAX/XHR, Web Sockets or a bunch of different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 options for this:

1. Long pulling
2. Server Sent Events (SSE)
3. Websocket

You can search about these methods and pros and cons but if you are using laravel, I suggest you to use socket.io and implement this feature with that. There are many tutorials about laravel with socket.io